# How to make my function loop every x second in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, setinterval

Can someone help me so that the function `myFunction` runs every `X` second. The function works perfectly if i only run it once, but when i begin using setInterval it is not run every x seconds. in the example below, it is sometimes executed after 5 sec and sometimes after 8 and so on. What should i change in my code? The api i´m using only grants 30 request per minute and i´m worried this function will exceed the limit as there are two getJSON.

```
setInterval(function () {
    myFunction();
}, 10000);

function myFunction() {

    $.getJSON("URL", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.getJSON("URL", function (data2) {
            console.log(data2);

            variable1 = data.Departure;
            variable2 = data2.Departure;

            text = "";
            variable3 = variable1.concat(variable2);
            variable3.sort(function (a, b) {
                return new Date('2017/01/16 ' + a.time) - new Date('2017/01/16 ' + b.time);
            })

            console.log(variable3);
            for (var i = 0; i < variable3.length; i++) {
                text += variable3[i].name.substring(13, 19) + " departure " + variable3[i].time.substring(0, 5) + " from " + variable3[i].stop.substring(8) + "<br>";
            }
            document.getElementById("Textn").innerHTML = text;
            console.log(text);

        });
    });
}

myFunction();
```

Comment: setTimeout function runs every x seconds.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: How do you know it's taking 5 seconds, 8 seconds, etc?

Comment: @jaikl How would you know how much time your function is taking ?

Comment: setTimeout function run only once @Roy

Comment: @JamesMonger i counted when the function was running. It should take at least a minimum of 10 seconds so something is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with the current implementation is that it uses asynchronous requests which may take more than 10 seconds(can't predict when the request is served).

The method `setInterval` will execute the `myFunction` irrespective of the previous requests were completed or not.

As a result next request will queue up to be executed. So you get *it is sometimes executed after 5 sec and sometimes after 8 and so on.*

You should use `setTimeout()` to recursively invoke the method instead of using `setInterval`

```
function myFunction() {
    $.getJSON("URL", function (data) {
        $.getJSON("URL", function (data2) {
            //Your existing code

            //Schedule it be executed after x * 1000 milliseconds
            setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);
        });
    });
}
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
callfunction();
var callCount = 1;
var repeater = setInterval(function () {
  if (callCount <= 30) {
    callfunction();
    callCount += 1;
  } else {
    clearInterval(repeater);
  }
}, 1000);

function callfunction()
{
  console.log((new Date()).getSeconds());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example **setInterval** implementation, This will run  every 1 second. **Your code should call the function every 10 seconds**, Couldn't find any issue in that.

```js
setInterval(myFunction, 1000); 

function myFunction(){
 console.log((new Date()).getSeconds());
};

myFunction();
```

Comment: Haven't answered reason behind _it is sometimes executed after 5 sec and sometimes after 8 and so on._